# ConstraintViolationException when create node using UniqueNodeFactory

Tags: neo4j

this test fails with error and I don't understand why.. 
I thought that `UniqueNodeFactory` create node only if it's not exist.
Of course I can do the same using Cypher but I want to understand what happens here..
Could somebody explain?
I am using neo4j 2.3.1.

```
public class SimpleTest {

private GraphDatabaseService graphService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    graphService = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory().newImpermanentDatabase();
    graphService.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (user:User) ASSERT user.userId IS UNIQUE");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    graphService.shutdown();
}

public static UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory createUserFactory(GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService) {

    return new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory(graphDatabaseService, "User") {

        @Override
        protected void initialize(Node created, Map<String, Object> properties) {
            created.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label("User"));
            created.setProperty("userId", properties.get("userId"));
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void testCreateUser() throws Exception {
    try (Transaction tx = graphService.beginTx()) {
        Node node = graphService.createNode(DynamicLabel.label("User"));
        node.setProperty("userId", 100L);
        tx.success();
    }

    try (Transaction tx = graphService.beginTx()) {
        UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory uniqueFactory = createUserFactory(graphService);
        uniqueFactory.getOrCreate("userId", 100L);
        tx.success();
    }
}

}
```

error :

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.UniquePropertyConstraintViolationKernelException: Node 0 already exists with label 0 and property 0=100
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.validateNoExistingNodeWithLabelAndProperty(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:165)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeSetProperty(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:140)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.nodeSetProperty(LockingStatementOperations.java:453)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeSetProperty(OperationsFacade.java:896)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeProxy.setProperty(NodeProxy.java:293)
... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I see the reason. I created **schema** index with Cypher and `UniqueNodeFactory` use **legacy** index. To fix the problem you need to create nodes only using `UniqueNodeFactory`.